# Moshe Levine book, Le Tabernacle

Tags: ark-aron-kodesh

Does anyone own the Moshe Levine book, Le Tabernacle? I would like to verify something. I was told that in this work, the author considers the Ark to be an electric capacitor. Can anyone confirm me if this work by Moshe Levine really says this?

Comment: This idea sounds familiar, not sure why...

Comment: Obviously the ark could act as a capacitor since it has 2 metal boxes separated by a wooden insulator but what charge is it meant to store?

Comment: Excellent observation, moreover admitted and granted, how would it have been loaded?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106824/shatnez-and-leviticus-16-4-23-32

Comment: I found this article: https://pe2bz.philpem.me.uk/Comm01/-%20-%20Parts-NonActive/Capacitor/ArkOfCovenant/AA-Main but no author for it.

Comment: I have used this as a joke. However the story of the one who touched the ark and was zapped when King David was trying to move it by wagon is the original source.

Comment: If no one answers by tomorrow, and if I have time, I'll try to see if I can access it in the university library.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the same book as The tabernacle : its structure and utensils / by Moshe Levin, just in Spanish. I don't think it's there. I've been through it several times. Granted that was a long time ago, but I feel like I would remember it if it was there.

Comment: Thank you so much @Harel13 let me know!

Comment: Thanks @Eliyahu for your comment, I also think it's not true...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to get back to you. I found the Hebrew version of the book. Nothing there connecting the Ark to electricity. I didn't read the whole book, but in general, it seemed to be pretty standard explanations of the Tabernacle.

Comment: Thanks so much! I imagined. Can you tell me briefly, what is the Ark to Moshe Levine himself?